# CXF Swagger2Feature adding securityDefinitions

Tags: java, cxf, swagger

I want to add Security Definition to my rest service using org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.swagger.Swagger2Feature. However I can not see any related method or any resource on how to do it. Below is the swagger doc which I want to generate using swagger2feature. How can I do it?

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: Based on "Basic Auth Example"
  description: >
    An example for how to use Auth with Swagger.

host: basic-auth-server.herokuapp.com
schemes:
  - http
  - https
securityDefinitions:
  Bearer:
    type: apiKey
    name: Authorization
    in: header
paths:
  /:
    get:
      security:
        - Bearer: []
      responses:
        '200':
          description: 'Will send `Authenticated`'
        '403': 
          description: 'You do not have necessary permissions for the resource'
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem and I couldn't find a suitable solution with CXF and its api. My solution is the following, create a class that extends the Swagger2Feature of CXF in order to override the addSwaggerResource method, to bound the security definition:

```
/** Name of the security definition */
public static final String SECURITY_NAME = "Bearer";

/** Extends the Swagger2Feature to use the security definition of Swagger */
@Provider(value = Provider.Type.Feature, scope = Provider.Scope.Server)
public class ExtendedSwagger2Feature extends Swagger2Feature {
    @Override
    protected void addSwaggerResource(Server server, Bus bus) {
        super.addSwaggerResource(server, bus);

        BeanConfig config = (BeanConfig) ScannerFactory.getScanner();
        Swagger swagger = config.getSwagger();
        swagger.securityDefinition(SECURITY_NAME, new ApiKeyAuthDefinition("authorization", In.HEADER));
    }
}
```

Then, as the **Swagger** instance has been modified after it has been loaded by the swagger api, you should "re-register" it in the context of the servlet (as I understand when I browsed the code of swagger). Have a look at **io.swagger.jaxrs.config.SwaggerContextService**. To do this, I had to create a new **ServletContextInitializer** in my servlet context:

```
return servletContext -> {
    BeanConfig scanner = (BeanConfig) ScannerFactory.getScanner();
    Swagger swagger = scanner.getSwagger();
    servletContext.setAttribute("swagger", swagger);
};
```

Putting in the context the **Swagger** configuration previously modified with the security definition allows the swagger api to take it into account correctly. Without this, our extended Swagger2Feature would not work.

With this changes, I was able to get a swagger.yaml file as the one you are expecting, especially the following part:

```
securityDefinitions:
  Bearer:
    type: apiKey
    name: Authorization
    in: header
```

I am using this solution in a Spring Boot application, here is my complete swagger configuration class, in case it helps someone:

```
package my.package.configuration;

import io.swagger.config.ScannerFactory;
import io.swagger.core.filter.AbstractSpecFilter;
import io.swagger.jaxrs.config.BeanConfig;
import io.swagger.model.ApiDescription;
import io.swagger.models.Operation;
import io.swagger.models.Swagger;
import io.swagger.models.auth.ApiKeyAuthDefinition;
import io.swagger.models.auth.In;
import org.apache.cxf.Bus;
import org.apache.cxf.annotations.Provider;
import org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Server;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.swagger.Swagger2Feature;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.DependsOn;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Configuration of the Swagger API to enable it with CXF.
 */
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfiguration {

    /** Name of the security definition */
    public static final String SECURITY_NAME = "Bearer";

    @Bean
    public Swagger2Feature swagger() {
        Swagger2Feature feature = new ExtendedSwagger2Feature();
        // Do your stuff with the configuration
        return feature;
    }

    /**
     * Register a custom {@link ServletContextInitializer} in the cxf servlet to expose the custom {@link Swagger2Feature}
     * otherwise the security definition added in the {@link ExtendedSwagger2Feature#addSwaggerResource} will not be
     * used by the swagger api because the original hook occurs during the super call.
     *
     * @see io.swagger.jaxrs.config.SwaggerContextService
     * @see org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.spring.SpringComponentScanServer
     *
     * @return a new instance of the {@link ServletContextInitializer}
     */
    @Bean
    @DependsOn("jaxRsServer")
    public ServletContextInitializer initializer() {
        return servletContext -> {
            BeanConfig scanner = (BeanConfig) ScannerFactory.getScanner();
            Swagger swagger = scanner.getSwagger();
            servletContext.setAttribute("swagger", swagger);
        };
    }

    /**
     * Extension of the {@link Swagger2Feature} because the one provided by CXF doesn't allow to use
     * feature of the Swagger API such as the security definition. This feature use the {@link ApiKeyAuthDefinition}
     * to transport the authorization header required by the application.
     */
    @Provider(value = Provider.Type.Feature, scope = Provider.Scope.Server)
    public static class ExtendedSwagger2Feature extends Swagger2Feature {
        @Override
        protected void addSwaggerResource(Server server, Bus bus) {
            super.addSwaggerResource(server, bus);

            BeanConfig config = (BeanConfig) ScannerFactory.getScanner();
            Swagger swagger = config.getSwagger();
            swagger.securityDefinition(SECURITY_NAME, new ApiKeyAuthDefinition("authorization", In.HEADER));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using Spring Boot, but I copied @Naoj's approach. (Thanks!)

For those not on Spring Boot, you can accomplish this in a startup servlet that loads after the CXF servlet.  You can also avoid extending the class if you just modify the Swagger instance when you grab it.

So in web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SwaggerServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>my.package.configuration.SwaggerStartupServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Then the servlet code:

```
/** Name of the security definition */
public static final String SECURITY_NAME = "Bearer";

@Override
public void init(final ServletConfig config) throws ServletException
{
    BeanConfig scanner = (BeanConfig) ScannerFactory.getScanner();
    Swagger swagger = scanner.getSwagger();
    swagger.securityDefinition(SECURITY_NAME, new ApiKeyAuthDefinition("Authorization", In.HEADER));
    config.getServletContext().setAttribute("swagger", swagger);
}
```