# Springboot, CXF 3.2.7, Swagger2Feature: Authorization header does not appear in the request headers

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, swagger, cxf, swagger-ui

I'm trying to integrate Swagger 2 into my API, which is implemented with CXF newest version: 3.2.7.

I tried lots of tutorials, the [CXF official documentation](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/swagger2feature.html), others too (e.g. [Spring Boot, Apache CXF, Swagger under JAX-RS](https://code.massoudafrashteh.com/spring-boot-cxf-jaxrs-hibernate-maven-swagger-ui/)).
The swagger official website does not help for me. [The swagger OpenAPI 2.0 authentication doc](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/authentication/) is not working, neighter [the OpenAPI 3.0](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/bearer-authentication/).

It is not working with component schemes of Open API 3.0.0, so i stayed with the apiKeyDefinition.

The one, which is working now can be found in this thread, in the answer of @Naoj: 
[CXF Swagger2Feature adding securityDefinitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39916418/cxf-swagger2feature-adding-securitydefinitions/42703569)

With this solution the swagger ui appeared and also the Autorize button is showing.
[image]

I fill the authentication form, and after that, I try to send requests with the swagger-ui. The problem is, that the Authorization header does not appear in the request, so I got 401 response.

---

In the pom:

```
<dependency>    
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-service-description-swagger</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>3.20.1</version>
</dependency>
```

My swagger configuration looks like this:

```
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("swagger")
    public Swagger2Feature swagger() {
        return new ExtendedSwagger2Feature();
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("jaxRsServer")
    public ServletContextInitializer initializer() {
        return servletContext -> {
            BeanConfig scanner = (BeanConfig) ScannerFactory.getScanner();
            Swagger swagger = scanner.getSwagger();
            servletContext.setAttribute("swagger", swagger);
        };
    }
}
```

The extended swagger feature is the following:

```
@Provider(value = Provider.Type.Feature, scope = Provider.Scope.Server)
public class ExtendedSwagger2Feature extends Swagger2Feature {

    @Override
    protected void addSwaggerResource(Server server, Bus bus) {
        super.addSwaggerResource(server, bus);

        BeanConfig config = (BeanConfig) ScannerFactory.getScanner();
        Swagger swagger = config.getSwagger();
        swagger.securityDefinition("Bearer", new ApiKeyAuthDefinition("authorization", In.HEADER));
    }
}
```

I try to configure Bearer JWT token based authentication. My application.yml contains the following:

```
swagger:
   basePath: /rest
   title: Backend Application
   description: Swagger documentation of Backend Application REST services
   license:
   licenceUrl:
   contact:
   resourcePackage: my.resource.package
   scan: true
   apiKeyAuthDefinition:
     name: Authorization
     in: header
     type: http
```

I import the SwaggerConfig into my @SpringBootApplication class like this:

```
@Import(SwaggerConfig.class)
```

It is working, as i see, swagger appeared and the title and description field is filled with the properties of my yml.

What am I missing? Any suggestions would be appretiated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share an executable sample on GitHub? That would save me some time to reproduce the issue...

Comment: It looks like CXF 3.2.7 uses Springboot 1.5.17.RELEASE, which is the old one. My goal of this CXF update is to upgrade Springboot, so I cannot create a working api with the new Springboot, and the new CXF version. Am I right? At this point I think, swagger is the smaller problem.

Comment: It also works with Spring Boot 2. I have working samples. Feel free to send us your issues to users@cxf.apache.org (see http://cxf.apache.org/mailing-lists.html).

Comment: I use `cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxrs::3.2.7` at the moment. Does it work with this, or I need to configure CXF manually?

Comment: Are you inheriting from spring-boot-starter-parent? Otherwise please import 2.1.1: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html#using-boot-maven-without-a-parent

Comment: 3.2.7 works well with Spring Boot 2. We have updated it for CXF 3.3.0 already but the version has not been released yet.

Comment: helo @DennisKieselhorst, I have a little project [here](https://github.com/marxmate/testcxfspringboot) , where you can find the server application, and in swagger I have the same situation, where you can authorize, but no Authorization header is sent. Also the spring-boot-starter-parent was a nice catch!

Comment: This project does not need jwt for response, so you will not see the 401, but you can see, that in the headers no Authorization header is sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your code and remove `ExtendedSwagger2Feature` and the `initializer()`. Modify your `swagger()` method as follows and the output will be the same:

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("swagger")
public Swagger2Feature swagger() {
    Swagger2Feature swagger2Feature = new Swagger2Feature();
    swagger2Feature.setSecurityDefinitions(Collections.singletonMap("bearerAuth",
            new ApiKeyAuthDefinition("Authorization", In.HEADER)));
    return swagger2Feature;
}
```

The reason for the token not being added to your request, is that `securityDefinitions` is just a declaration for the available schemes. You need to apply it to the operation by adding (to your TestResource interface):

```
@Api( authorizations = @Authorization( value = "bearerAuth" ))
```

You will notice a lock icon next to the operation in Swagger UI. Currently it's not there.

Btw. you should use the newer `OpenApiFeature` instead of the old `Swagger2Feature`. Happy to answer questions, if you have problems with it.

Comment: Imagine that you have 80 resources. Can you configure the security easily with openapi, for every resources in one place?

Comment: Switch to OpenApiFeature and use @OpenApiDefinition along with security requirements as explained here: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Annotations#OpenAPIDefinition

Comment: Might be possible with old Swagger and @Api on root level as well but never tried that.

Comment: Works like a charm with both of Swagger2Feature and OpenApiFeature, thank you!